# combine text files column-wise

Tags: text-processing, table

I have two text files. The first one has content:

```
Languages
Recursively enumerable
Regular
```

while the second one has content:

```
Minimal automaton
Turing machine
Finite
```

I want to combine them into one file column-wise. So I tried `paste 1 2` and its output is:

```
Languages   Minimal automaton
Recursively enumerable  Turing machine
Regular Finite
```

However I would like to have the columns aligned well such as

```
Languages               Minimal automaton
Recursively enumerable  Turing machine
Regular                 Finite
```

I was wondering if it would be possible to achieve that without manually handling?

---

Added:

Here is another example, where Bruce method almost nails it, except some slight misalignment about which I wonder why?

```
$ cat 1
Chomsky hierarchy
Type-0
—

$ cat 2
Grammars
Unrestricted

$ paste 1 2 | pr -t -e20
Chomsky hierarchy   Grammars
Type-0              Unrestricted
—                    (no common name)
```

Comment: That last example, with misalignment, is a doozy. I can duplicate it on Arch linux, pr (GNU coreutils) 8.12.  I can't duplicate it on an elderly Slackware (11.0) I also have around: pr (GNU coreutils) 5.97.  The problem is with the '-' character, and it's in pr, not paste.

Comment: I get the same thing with the EM-DASH with both `pr` and `expand` ... [`columns`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16443/combine-text-files-column-wise/16465#16465) avoids this issue.

Comment: I've produced output for most of the different answers except for *awk + paste*, which will left-shift right-most column(s) if a left file is shorter than any t the right of it. The same, and more, applies to *'paste + column'* which also has this problem with blank lines in left column(s)... If you want to see all the outputs together. here is the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com/643692/ I've used 4 columns.

Comment: I just noticed something misleading on the *paste.ubuntu* link... I originally set the data up for testing my scripts, (and that led on to doing the others)... so the fields which say `➀ unicode may render oddly` `but the column count is ok` *definitely* does *not* apply to `wc-paste-pr` and `wc-paste-pr` They do show column count differences.. The others are ok.

Comment: @BruceEdiger: The alignment problem occurs when non-ASCII characters are used (in his question, the OP used a dash (—) instead of a minus (-) character), most probably due to a bad or no handling by `pr` of the multibyte characters in the current locale (usually UTF8).

Answer (score 93, accepted):

You just need the [`column`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/column) command, and tell it to use tabs to separate columns

```
paste file1 file2 | column -s $'\t' -t
```

---

To address the "empty cell" controversy, we just need the `-n` option to `column`:

```
$ paste <(echo foo; echo; echo barbarbar) <(seq 3) | column -s $'\t' -t
foo        1
2
barbarbar  3

$ paste <(echo foo; echo; echo barbarbar) <(seq 3) | column -s $'\t' -tn
foo        1
           2
barbarbar  3
```

My column man page indicates `-n` is a "Debian GNU/Linux extension." My Fedora system does not exhibit the empty cell problem: it appears to be derived from BSD and the man page says "Version 2.23 changed the -s option to be non-greedy"

Comment: glenn: You are the hero of the hour! I knew there was something like this around, but I couldn't rememeber it. I've been lurking on this question; waiting for *you* :) ... `column`, of course; how obvious (in hindsight) +1... Thanks...

Comment: I've just noticed that `column -s $'\t' -t` ignores empty *cells*, resulting in all subsequent cells to the right of it (on that line) to moved to the left; ie, as a result of a blank line in a file, or it being shorter... :(

Comment: @masi, corrected

Comment: -n does not work in RHEL. Is there an alternative?

Comment: I can finally comment, so want to note that I previously added an answer below that addresses Peter.O's issue with runs of empty cells by using nulls.

Answer (score 19):

You're looking for the handy dandy `pr` command:

```
paste file1 file2 | pr -t -e24
```

The "-e24" is "expand tab stops to 24 spaces".  Luckily, `paste` puts a tab-character between columns, so `pr` can expand it.  I chose 24 by counting the characters in "Recursively enumerable" and adding 2.

Comment: Thanks! What does "expand tab stops to 24 spaces" mean?

Comment: I also update with an example where your method almost nails it except a slight misalignment.

Comment: Traditionally "tabstops" hit every 8 spaces. "123TABabc" would get printed out with the 'a' character 8 character-widths from the start of the line. Setting it to 24 would put the 'a' at 24 char widths from the start of the line.

Comment: You say *the "-e24" is "expand tab stops to 24 spaces"*, so why not use the [`expand`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/expand.html) command directly: `paste file1 file2 | expand -t 24` ?

Comment: Can you please compare this answer to techno's answer?

Comment: @Masi -  my answer is similar but less complicated that @techno's answer below. It doesn't invoke `sed` so there's one process that doesn't run. It uses `pr` which is an ancient command, dating to Unix SysV days, I think, so it might exist on more installs than `expand`. It's just old school, in short.

Comment: The difference between the two approaches is that using `column` will allow for varying column lengths rather than the fixed of `pr` or `expand`. So it depends upon what you need and can live with.

Answer (score 10):

*Update*: Here ia a much simpler script (that the one at the end of the question) for tabulated output. Just pass filename to it as you would to `paste`... It uses `html` to make the frame, so it is tweakable. It does preserve multiple spaces, and the column alignment is preserved when it encounters unicode characters. However, the way the editor or viewer renderers the unicode is another matter entirely...

```
┌──────────────────────┬────────────────┬──────────┬────────────────────────────┐
│ Languages            │ Minimal        │ Chomsky  │ Unrestricted               │
├──────────────────────┼────────────────┼──────────┼────────────────────────────┤
│ Recursive            │ Turing machine │ Finite   │     space indented         │
├──────────────────────┼────────────────┼──────────┼────────────────────────────┤
│ Regular              │ Grammars       │          │ ➀ unicode may render oddly │
├──────────────────────┼────────────────┼──────────┼────────────────────────────┤
│ 1 2  3   4    spaces │                │ Symbol-& │ but the column count is ok │
├──────────────────────┼────────────────┼──────────┼────────────────────────────┤
│                      │                │          │ Context                    │
└──────────────────────┴────────────────┴──────────┴────────────────────────────┘
```

---

```
#!/bin/bash
{ echo -e "<html>\n<table border=1 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>"
  paste "$@" |sed -re 's#(.*)#\x09\1\x09#' -e 's#\x09# </pre></td>\n<td><pre> #g' -e 's#^ </pre></td>#<tr>#' -e 's#\n<td><pre> $#\n</tr>#'
  echo -e "</table>\n</html>"
} |w3m -dump -T 'text/html'
```

### ---

*A synopsis of the tools* presented in the answers (so far).
I've had a pretty close look at them; here is what I've found:

`paste` # This tool is common to all the answers presented so far
        # It can handle multiple files; therefore multiple columns... Good!
        # It delimits each column with a Tab... Good.
        # Its output is not tabulated.

All the tools below all remove this delimiter!... Bad if you need a delimiter.

`column` # It removes the Tab delimiter, so field identificaton is purely by columns which it seems to handle quite well.. I haven't spotted anything awry... # Aside from not having a unique delimiter, it works fine!

`expand` # Only has a single tab setting, so it is unpredictable beyond 2 columns # The alignment of columns is not accurate when handling unicode, and it removes the Tab delimiter, so field identificaton is purely by column alignment

`pr` # Only has a single tab setting, so it is unpredictable beyond 2 columns. # The alignment of columns is not accurate when handling unicode, and it removes the Tab delimiter, so field identificaton is purely by column alignment

To me, `column` it the obvious best soluton as a one-liner.. It you want either the delimiter, or an ASCII-art tabluation of your files, read on, otherwise.. `columns` is pretty darn good :)...

---

Here is a script which takes any numper of files and creates an ASCII-art tabulated presentation.. (Bear in mind that unicode may not render to the expected width, eg. ௵ which is a single character. This is quite different to the column numbers being wrong, as is the case in some of the utilities mentioned above.) ... The script's output, shown below, is from 4 input files, named F1 F2 F3 F4...

```
+------------------------+-------------------+-------------------+--------------+
| Languages              | Minimal automaton | Chomsky hierarchy | Grammars     |
| Recursively enumerable | Turing machine    | Type-0            | Unrestricted |
| Regular                | Finite            | —                 |              |
| Alphabet               |                   | Symbol            |              |
|                        |                   |                   | Context      |
+------------------------+-------------------+-------------------+--------------+
```

---

```
#!/bin/bash

# Note: The next line is for testing purposes only!
set F1 F2 F3 F4 # Simulate commandline filename args $1 $2 etc...

p=' '                                # The pad character
# Get line and column stats
cc=${#@}; lmax=                      # Count of columns (== input files)
for c in $(seq 1 $cc) ;do            # Filenames from the commandline 
  F[$c]="${!c}"        
  wc=($(wc -l -L <${F[$c]}))         # File length and width of longest line 
  l[$c]=${wc[0]}                     # File length  (per file)
  L[$c]=${wc[1]}                     # Longest line (per file) 
  ((lmax<${l[$c]})) && lmax=${l[$c]} # Length of longest file
done
# Determine line-count deficits  of shorter files
for c in $(seq 1 $cc) ;do  
  ((${l[$c]}<lmax)) && D[$c]=$((lmax-${l[$c]})) || D[$c]=0 
done
# Build '\n' strings to cater for short-file deficits
for c in $(seq 1 $cc) ;do
  for n in $(seq 1 ${D[$c]}) ;do
    N[$c]=${N[$c]}$'\n'
  done
done
# Build the command to suit the number of input files
source=$(mktemp)
>"$source" echo 'paste \'
for c in $(seq 1 $cc) ;do
    ((${L[$c]}==0)) && e="x" || e=":a -e \"s/^.{0,$((${L[$c]}-1))}$/&$p/;ta\""
    >>"$source" echo '<(sed -re '"$e"' <(cat "${F['$c']}"; echo -n "${N['$c']}")) \'
done
# include the ASCII-art Table framework
>>"$source" echo ' | sed  -e "s/.*/| & |/" -e "s/\t/ | /g" \'   # Add vertical frame lines
>>"$source" echo ' | sed -re "1 {h;s/[^|]/-/g;s/\|/+/g;p;g}" \' # Add top and botom frame lines 
>>"$source" echo '        -e "$ {p;s/[^|]/-/g;s/\|/+/g}"'
>>"$source" echo  
# Run the code
source "$source"
rm     "$source"
exit
```

---

Here is my original answer (trimmed a bit in lieu of the above script)

Using `wc` to get the column width, and `sed` to right pad with a *visible* character `.` (just for this example)... and then `paste` to join the two columns with a *Tab* char...

```
paste <(sed -re :a -e 's/^.{1,'"$(($(wc -L <F1)-1))"'}$/&./;ta' F1) F2

# output (No trailing whitespace)
Languages.............  Minimal automaton
Recursively enumerable  Turing machine
Regular...............  Finite
```

If you  want to pad out the right column:

```
paste <( sed -re :a -e 's/^.{1,'"$(($(wc -L <F1)-1))"'}$/&./;ta' F1 ) \
      <( sed -re :a -e 's/^.{1,'"$(($(wc -L <F2)-1))"'}$/&./;ta' F2 )  

# output (With trailing whitespace)
Languages.............  Minimal automaton
Recursively enumerable  Turing machine...
Regular...............  Finite...........
```

Comment: Thanks! You have done quite a lot of work. That's amazing.

Answer (score 5):

You're almost there. `paste` puts a tab character between each column, so all you need to do is expand the tabs. (I assume your files don't contain tabs.) You do need to determine the width of the left column. With (recent enough) GNU utilities, `wc -L` shows the length of the longest line. On other systems, make a first pass with awk. The `+1` is the amount of blank space you want between columns.

```
paste left.txt right.txt | expand -t $(($(wc -L <left.txt) + 1))
paste left.txt right.txt | expand -t $(awk 'n<length {n=length} END {print n+1}')
```

If you have the BSD column utility, you can use it to determine the column width and expand the tabs in one go. (`␉` is a literal tab character; under bash/ksh/zsh you can use `$'\t'` instead, and in any shell you can use `"$(printf '\t')"`.)

```
paste left.txt right.txt | column -s '␉' -t
```

Comment: In my version of `wc`, the command needs to be: `wc -L <left.txt` ... because, when a filename is spedified as a command line *arg*, its name is output to stdout

Answer (score 5):

I'm unable to comment on glenn jackman's answer, so am adding this to address the issue of empty cells that Peter.O noted. Adding a null char prior to each tab eliminates the runs of delimiters that are treated as a single break and addresses the issue. (I originally used spaces, but using the null char eliminates the extra space between columns.)

```
paste file1 file2 | sed 's/\t/\0\t/g' | column -s $'\t' -t
```

If the null char causes problems for various reasons, try either:

```
paste file1 file2 | sed 's/\t/ \t/g' | column -s $'\t' -t
```

or

```
paste file1 file2 | sed $'s/\t/ \t/g' | column -s $'\t' -t
```

Both `sed` and `column` appear to vary in implementation across flavors and versions of Unix/Linux, especially BSD (and Mac OS X) vs. GNU/Linux.

Comment: That sed command appears to do nothing. I replace the column command with `od -c` and I don't see any null bytes. This is on centos and ubuntu.

Comment: This worked for me in RedHat EL4. Both sed and column seem to vary over time and system. In Ubuntu 14.4 using `\0` didn't work as a `null` in sed, but `\x0` did. However, then column gave a `line too long` error.

Simplest thing seems to be to use a space and live with the extra character.

Answer (score 4):

This is multi-step, so it's non-optimal, but here goes.

1) Find the length of the longest line in `file1.txt`.

```
while read line
do
echo ${#line}
done < file1.txt | sort -n | tail -1
```

With your example, the longest line is 22.

2) Use awk to pad `file1.txt`, padding the each line less than 22 characters up to 22 with the `printf` statement.

```
awk 'FS="---" {printf "%-22s\n", $1}' < file1.txt > file1-pad.txt
```

Note: For FS, use a string that does not exist in `file1.txt`.

3) Use paste as you did before.

```
$ paste file1-pad.txt file2.txt
Languages               Minimal automaton
Recursively enumerable  Turing machine
Regular                 Finite
```

If this is something you do often, this can easily be turned into a script.

Comment: In your code to find the longest line, you need `while IFS= read -r line`, otherwise the shell will mangle whitespace and backslashes. But the shell isn't the best tool for that job; recent versions of GNU coreutils have `wc -L` (see fred's answer), or you can use awk: `awk 'n<length {n=length} END {print +n}'`.

Answer (score 1):

Building on [bahamat’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/16443/80216#16445):
this can be done entirely in `awk`,
reading the files only once and not creating any temporary files. 
To solve the problem as stated, do

```
awk '
        NR==FNR { if (length > max_length) max_length = length
                  max_FNR = FNR
                  save[FNR] = $0
                  next
                }
                { printf "%-*s", max_length+2, save[FNR]
                  print
                }
        END     { if (FNR < max_FNR) {
                        for (i=FNR+1; i <= max_FNR; i++) print save[i]
                  }
                }
    '   file1 file2
```

As with many `awk` scripts of this ilk, the above first reads `file1`,
saving all the data in the `save` array
and simultaneously computing the maximum line length. 
Then it reads `file2`
and prints the saved (`file1`) data side-by-side
with the current (`file2`) data. 
Finally, if `file1` is longer than `file2` (has more lines),
we print the last few lines of `file1`
(the ones for which there is no corresponding line in the second column).

Regarding the `printf` format:

- `"%-nns"` prints a string left-justified
  in a field *`nn`* characters wide.
- `"%-*s", nn` does the same thing —
  the `*` tells it to take the field width from the next parameter.
- By using `maxlength+2` for *`nn`*,
  we get two spaces between the columns. 
  Obviously the **`+2`** can be adjusted.

The above script works only for two files. 
It can trivially be modified to handle three files,
or to handle four files, etc.,
but this would be tedious and is left as an exercise. 
However, it turns out not to be hard to modify it to handle
***any number*** of files:

```
awk '
        FNR==1  { file_num++ }
                { if (length > max_length[file_num]) max_length[file_num] = length
                  max_FNR[file_num] = FNR
                  save[file_num,FNR] = $0
                }
        END     { for (j=1; j<=file_num; j++) {
                        if (max_FNR[j] > global_max_FNR) global_max_FNR = max_FNR[j]
                  }
                  for (i=1; i<=global_max_FNR; i++) {
                        for (j=1; j<file_num; j++) printf "%-*s", max_length[j]+2, save[j,i]
                        print save[file_num,i]
                  }
                }
    '   file*
```

This is very similar to my first script, except

- It turns `max_length` into an array.
- It turns `max_FNR` into an array.
- It turns `save` into a two-dimensional array.
- It reads *all* the files, saving *all* the contents. 
  Then it writes out *all* the output from the `END` block.

Comment: I know that this question is old; I just stumbled upon it.  I agree that `paste` is the best solution; specifically, glenn jackman’s `paste file1 file2 | column -s $'\t' -t`.  But I thought it would be fun to try to improve on the `awk` approach.