# merging text files into one

Tags: merge

I have four text files each containing a single field. I want to convert them into a single text file with four fields (one from each file). How can I do this using shell scripting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do:

```
paste file_1 file_2 file_3 file_4
```

If you want pretty printing (given that the number of lines are same for all the files), then:

```
paste 1 2 3 4 | column -t
```

Comment: note that `column` is likely to break things for files that don't have the same number of lines.

Comment: @peterph: yes, edited.

Comment: @peterph - depends what switches his/her version of `column` accepts...  see glenn jackman's answer [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/16443) - it works fine with files that don't have the same number of lines.

Comment: @don_crissti *"... is **likely** to break things..."* You'll have to fiddle with it to make sure things will be what you want them to be.

Answer (score 2):

The [paste](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/paste.html) command does exactly what you're looking for, and the good news is that it's POSIX-standard, so it's available effectively everywhere.