# Sum two columns from different files

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have two files like this:

File1:

```
-54.005 -67.405 0.1

-54.05 -68.7833 0.2 

-54.05 -68.7333 0.3
```

File2:

```
-54.005 -67.4050   70    12.7

 -54.05 -68.7833  167    12.5

 -54.05 -68.7333  205    12.6
```

I would like to get a file that sums column 3 from `file1` with column 4 from `file2` with the following output:

```
-54.005 -67.4050   70    12.8

 -54.05 -68.7833  167    12.7

 -54.05 -68.7333  205    12.9
```

I tried with the following command:

```
cat file1 | awk '{n=$3; getline <"file2"; print "" $1,$2,$3,n+$4}' > output.txt
```

but it did not succeed and I couldn't find this type of answer in this site.

Comment: Your unaffected output columns appear to come from file2. Is that correct? In your output you have changed columns 8 and 12. What is the rule for those?

Comment: the system does not allows me to edit as I want. The format is the one I posted as an answer by mistake.

Comment: ok. I edited now...

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool that could merge two files into one: [merging text files into one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182736/merging-text-files-into-one)

```
paste file1 file2 | awk '{ print $3 + $13; }'
```

Add other columns to this, but note that columns in file 2 start with $10.

Comment: I edited the post. I think now is better understood. Sorry, but the system edited first in a wrong way.

Comment: `paste file1 suma_file2 | awk '{ print $4 " "  $5 " " $6 " " $3 + $7; }'` worked for me

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of NR and FNR in awk.

```
awk 'FNR==NR { _a[FNR]=$3;} NR!=FNR { $4 += _a[FNR]; print;  }'  file1 file2
```