# copy and replace column using unix

Tags: text-processing

I want to copy a first column from a file(.txt) and replace it with first column of second file in text delimited using Unix code.

input file format 
file 1

```
01/01/2007
02/01/2007
03/01/2007
04/01/2007
```

file 2

```
20070101 10.2317  79.1638   6.0  26.7  20.9   0.8  14.0  98.6
20070102 10.2317  79.1638   5.6  26.5  20.8   1.9  13.6  98.0
20070103 10.2317  79.1638   7.5  27.7  20.8   0.1  15.8  96.4
20070104 10.2317  79.1638   8.1  26.0  19.6   0.0  15.5  94.1
```

output required

```
01/01/2007  10.2317   79.1638   6.0  26.7  20.9   0.8  14.0  98.6
02/01/2007  10.2317   79.1638   5.6  26.5  20.8   1.9  13.6  98.0
03/01/2007  10.2317   79.1638   7.5  27.7  20.8   0.1  15.8  96.4
04/01/2007  10.2317   79.1638   8.1  26.0  19.6   0.0  15.5  94.1
```

Comment: Is this tab-delimited data?

Comment: There are already 2 questions about this topic: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145648/merging-columns-from-two-separate-files - http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16443/combine-text-files-column-wise - None of them helped you?

Comment: @nwildner They are similar in nature, but neither involves removing one column.

Comment: Do you really need to past from file 1, or do you really want to just changed the date format in column 1 of line 2 (e.g. with `sed 's,^\([0-9]\{4\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\),\3/\2/\1,'` or similar)?

Answer (score 3):

```
$ cut -d' ' -f 2- file2 | paste file1 -
```

The `cut` will remove the first column from `file2` (`-f 2-` means "output fields (columns) 2 onwards only").  The result of that will be passed to `paste` which will put the contents of `file1` in the first column. The `-` in the `paste` command is a placeholder for whatever is delivered on standard input (the pipe from `cut` in this case).

Step by step:

```
$ cut -d' ' -f 2- file2
10.2317  79.1638   6.0  26.7  20.9   0.8  14.0  98.6
10.2317  79.1638   5.6  26.5  20.8   1.9  13.6  98.0
10.2317  79.1638   7.5  27.7  20.8   0.1  15.8  96.4
10.2317  79.1638   8.1  26.0  19.6   0.0  15.5  94.1

$ cut -d' ' -f 2- file2 | paste file1 -
01/01/2007      10.2317  79.1638   6.0  26.7  20.9   0.8  14.0  98.6
02/01/2007      10.2317  79.1638   5.6  26.5  20.8   1.9  13.6  98.0
03/01/2007      10.2317  79.1638   7.5  27.7  20.8   0.1  15.8  96.4
04/01/2007      10.2317  79.1638   8.1  26.0  19.6   0.0  15.5  94.1
```

The `cut` command is expecting tab-delimited input, but since I copied and pasted from your question, it's space-delimited.  If the original data is actually tab-delimited, remove the `-d' '` from the `cut` command.

The `paste` command will add a tab between column 1 and 2 by default.  If you want a space instead, use `paste -d' ' file1 -`.

In [another question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/338300/replace-first-column-of-file-by-command-output?noredirect=1&lq=1), it was asked how to use the already existing date in `file2` here, and do away with the first file completely.

[I ended up with](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/338311/116858)

```
$ paste <( date -f <( cut -d ' ' -f 1 file2 ) +"%d/%m/%Y" ) \
        <( cut -d ' ' -f 2- file2 )
01/01/2007      10.2317  79.1638   6.0  26.7  20.9   0.8  14.0  98.6
02/01/2007      10.2317  79.1638   5.6  26.5  20.8   1.9  13.6  98.0
03/01/2007      10.2317  79.1638   7.5  27.7  20.8   0.1  15.8  96.4
04/01/2007      10.2317  79.1638   8.1  26.0  19.6   0.0  15.5  94.1
```

Note, this requires a shell that understands process substitution (`<( ... )`), like `bash` or `ksh`, and it also requires GNU's implementation of `date`.

A bit of explanation may be in order:

The process substitution `<( ... )` *more or less* creates a temporary file containing the output of the command within the parenthesis (actually a FIFO under `/dev/fd`). So the whole command will go through two steps substitutions:

```
paste <( date -f output_of_cut1 +"%d/%m/%Y" ) \
      output_from_cut2
```

`date -f filename` will read the dates in file `filename` and format each of them according to the given format string.

Then:

```
paste output_from_date output_from_cut2
```

which will paste together the columns with the output from `date` as the first column and the output of the second `cut` as the other columns.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on  `awk` version, you can transform first column with:

```
awk '{$1=substr($0,7,2)"/"substr($0,5,2)"/"substr($0,1,4); print $0}'  FILE2.csv
```

example:

```
echo "20070101 10.2317  79.1638   6.0  26.7  20.9   0.8  14.0  98.6"  | awk '{$1=substr($0,7,2)"/"substr($0,5,2)"/"substr($0,1,4); print $0}'
```

returns:

```
 01/01/2007 10.2317 79.1638 6.0 26.7 20.9 0.8 14.0 98.6
```

Notes:

First part redefine the value of the first columns

```
 $1=substr($0,7,2)"/"substr($0,5,2)"/"substr($0,1,4)
```

and `print $0` prints entire line with the first column redefined

Answer (score 1):

You can use awk for this:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[++i]=$1;next}{$1=a[++k]; print}' file1 file2
```

`NR==FNR` is a pattern meaning: `{a[++i]=$1;next}` *is executed on each record(i.e. line) in file1.*

`a[++i]=$1;next` means: *save the first field of the record(i.e. line) in the array with the index of the record-number(i.e. the line-number of file1), then read in the next record*

`$1=a[++k]; print` means: *copy the content of the array with indx k into the first field of the current record (i.e. line)* (which is always the k-th record (i.e. line) of file2).

Comment: but sir, the out put is printing below not in line

Comment: What do you mean? On my machine I get the desired output.

Comment: i am getting the output like this                                                           31/12/2007
 10.2317 79.1638 6.0 26.7 20.9 0.8 14.0 98.6. The date is printed first and the second data is printed last of it as shown above

Comment: I can't follow you, sorry. If you are unhappy with the result, you can use one of the other answers.